# How do I migrate DPP4 photo collections to another computer?

Tags: canon-dpp

I have a few image collections created in Canon's Digital Photo Professional 4. I'm moving to a new computer and want to migrate my photo library.

The question is where does the DPP4 stores the information about the collections so I can migrate them to DPP4 installed on the new computer?

Thanks in advance!